# Spring Batch How to get JobExecution Object in Process Listner

Tags: spring-batch

I have requirement in my project what ever exception occur in ItemProccesor need to store Exception in JobExecution context and at the end of JobExecution send mail for Exceptional records but how to get JobExecution Object in processListner?
 I tried using @beforestep in processListner but JobExecution object was null is there any way to get JobExecution context in process Listner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution in spring batch for above issue, need to specify jobscope in process listener and access job execution context in listner class code is mention below.

```
 @Bean
    @JobScope
    public CaliberatedProcessorListener calibratedProcessorListener() {

        return new CaliberatedProcessorListener();
    }
public class CaliberatedProcessorListener <T, S> implements ItemProcessListener<T, S> {

    @Value("#{jobExecution}")
    public JobExecution jobExecution;

    @Override
    public void beforeProcess(T calibratedProessorInPut) {

        // // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void afterProcess(T calibratedProessorInput, S calibratedProessorOutPut) {

        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessError(T item, Exception calibratedProcessorEx) {

        FtpEmailData ftpEmailData = (FtpEmailData) jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get("calDeviceBatchInfo");
        ftpEmailData.getExceptionList().add(new CalibratedDeviceException(calibratedProcessorEx.getMessage()));
    }

}
```